# column with mixed decimals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a value column with all sorts of problems it returns an object dtype and it goes like this :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Observation':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], 
        'Value':['5.6' , '1 068,0', '1 956.3', '', 'NaN', '65,0', 'nan', '23,5', '30.0']} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

the main issues are :

- mixed decimals (point and comma)
- thousand separator in both types
- mixed NaN and nan and the empty string for na values
- point 0 or comma 0 at the end

the desired outcome is a column with float64 datatype with correct NaN values

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas `series.replace` accepts a dictionary and `regex` option:

```
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'].replace({' ':'', ',':'.'}, regex=True), 
                            errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
  Observation   Value
0           1     5.6
1           2  1068.0
2           3  1956.3
3           4     NaN
4           5     NaN
5           6    65.0
6           7     NaN
7           8    23.5
8           9    30.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
 df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'].str.replace(',', '.').str.replace(' ', ''), 
                             errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
    Observation   Value
0             1     5.6
1             2  1068.0
2             3  1956.3
3             4     NaN
4             5     NaN
5             6    65.0
6             7     NaN
7             8    23.5
8             9    30.0
```

Comment: It worked like a charm..thanks...

Answer (score 2):

First you need to preprocess your data, i.e. replace blank spaces, commas and finally remove nans.
Here's how I'd do.

```
df['Value']=df['Value'].astype(str)
df['Value']=df['Value'].apply(lambda x:x.replace(' ',''))
df['Value']=df['Value'].apply(lambda x:x.replace(',','.'))
```

You can add other preprocessing procedures, according to how your data are depicted.
I encapsulate the casting procedure in a function, to further re-use.

```
def cast_float(x):
   try:
      return float(x)
   except:
      return np.NaN

df['Value']=df['Value'].apply(cast_float)
```